# How do I make an App Inventor app be a target for Chrome Share web page?

Tags: app-inventor

This is for an Android app that I want to develop using App Inventor, to read the content of a web page when a user decides to share it to my app.

1. When you are on a web page, in Chrome, you have the option to "Share" it. If you click this option, you get a list of available apps on your Android device to pick from. How can I make my app appear on that list?
2. How do I make my app read the web page that is shared by the user to my app? I want to read the text, not render the web page.

Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately not possible, [see also here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/odPZ0N88oL0/66an_P7CMfMJ)

Comment: As I have answered you already before Taifun: it is really not possible yet with App Inventor. I don't understand why some people can't accept such an answer and vote to delete it. In this case it was unfortunately the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with App Inventor, unfortunately.

Comment: How do you know this? Can you add a reference to some documentation that states this officially?

Comment: No, I have no reference, but to achieve this, you need to modify the matifest and define the intent filter. Up to now, the App Inventor has no feature to define this functionality for the android app.